# Spark Scala - Show Distinct Values for All Columns in One Table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, types, distinct-values

This line of code prints what I want for one column.  But I would like to print the distinct values for all columns side by side.

```
testDF.select('col_name).distinct().show

+--------+
|col_name|
+--------+
|    null|
|      No|
|     Yes|
+--------+
```

Part of what I am trying to figure out is how to determine which Scala type to use in this situation?

```
val c1 = testDF.select('col_name).distinct()
c1: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [col_name: string]
```

How do I take several Row types and combine them as columns that show only the distinct values of the columns to which they refer in one table(a single Spark DataFrame)?

Comment: what do you mean by "side by side"? Each column containing its distinct values? What if one column as X such values and the another has X+1 such values - what would be the value of the first column in that extra row? It seems that a DataFrame might not be a good fit for storing such a result (as it forces all records to have the same schema)

Comment: Take from DF1 only the distinct values for all columns and save as DF2 then show.  I do that for one column, but want to do for all columns.  The end result would look like a SELECT * on a table but instead of all, it would return only the distinct values.

Comment: testDF.select('rev_stop, 'went_on_backorder).distinct().show()

This gives the right layout, but gives the cartesian product.

Comment: can you use  dropDuplicates method, which is available in dataframe.  testDF .dropDuplicates("columnName1","columnName2").show

Comment: Sorry, no, that gives the cartesian product.  Interesting thought, but I think this has more to do with what data types I pass from one DF to the next. ---- In other words, it is not a question of getting the correct values in a particular column, rather it is: how to combine those results for many columns?  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] => ?

Comment: As @TzachZohar has pointed out that you will have inconsistent rows for two distinct columns. But still I would like you to update the question with you sample input dataframe and expected output dataframe. It would help us to help you with right suggestion. :)